# About OpenGl on Mac

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics

I am a newbie on OpenGl..I am working on Mac OS platform..What is the best tutorial or guideline available to know the basics of openGl on Mac platorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps Apple's own code sample can help you :  [Cocoa OpenGL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html)